# How can I set Default approvers from the GitLab repo side?

Tags: gitlab

I got to know GitLab has a feature called, [Default approvers](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/07/29/feature-highlight-merge-request-approvals/).
And I found many conversations going around this topic in the GitLab EE issue tracking. 
Some have suggested to keep a `.yaml` file to keep the **Default approvers** list, And someone told that `readme.md` is the file.

And also found a feature request which is still in the backlog:

[Default Approvers for a merge request depend on what team a user is in](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/3007)

But I would appreciate if someone can tell what is the latest feature (let's say in v10.3.X) with GitLab to keep list of Default Approvers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only closed recent issue I can find related to approval assignment is [1593](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1593), which is closed by [MR 1892](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/1892/diffs):

> #### Selecting individual approvers
>
> GitLab restricts the users that can be selected to be individual approvers. Only these can be selected and appear in the search box:
>   - Members of the current project
>   - Members of the parent group of the current project
>   - Members of a group that have access to the current project via a share

Those are the default members available to be selected as approvers.
There isn't yet a *custom* default list implemented.